# Where can I find Taizé groups in Barcelona?

Tags: spain, culture, religion, barcelona

I'm staying in Barcelona for a few days. Where I live use to go to the Taize' prayer in my Parrish. I know the prayer is international and that many people, after coming back to Taizé, start to pray the same way in small groups within the local church.

I really would like, in any of the days I'm there, to get in contact with local communities and to join the prayer.

Does any of you know if there are any regular Taizé prayers in Barcelona  and if it would be possible to join them?

Comment: Have you tried to contact any of these yet: https://www.taize.fr/es_article4375.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official site for the Taizé community in Catalonia is [Acollida de Barcelona](https://acollidabcn.org/) (also, [English version](https://acollidabcneng.wordpress.com/) but under construction).

In the section [Pregàries Taizé a Catalunya](https://acollidabcn.org/pregaries-de-taize-a-catalunya/) I read:

> Barcelona: Oració cada quart dimarts de mes a las 20.45h a la Parròquia Mare de Déu dels Dolors, c/ Begur, 10, 08028 Barcelona. Per més detalls contactar: E-mail
>
> Barcelona: Oració cada divendres CENTRE CRISTIÀ DELS UNIVERSITARIS, c/Villaroel 81. L’oració comença a les 22h i dura fins les 24h. Per més detalls, contactar a: Salva Tremps, E-mail o consultar: Jesus Amic
>
> Barcelona: Oració comú cada segon i quart dimarts de cada mes a la capella de la parròquia de Maria Auxiliadora, Pg Sant Joan Bosco, 70, Barcelona. Per a més informació: pregaries taize sarria
>
> Barcelona: Oració comú tots els divendres a les 21.00h a l’Església Josepets de Gràcia, plaça Lesseps, 25. Per a més detalls, contactar a: E-mail

That is:

> Barcelona: Prayer every 4th Tuesday of the month at 20.45 h in the Parrish Mare de Déu dels Dolors, c/ Begur, 10, 08028 Barcelona. [More info here](http://www.taize.fr/es_article4375.html#)
>
> Barcelona: Prayer every Friday in the CENTRE CRISTIÀ DELS UNIVERSITARIS, c/Villaroel 81. The prayer starts at 22h and finishes at 24h. More info, contact with: Salva Tremps, [E-mail](http://www.taize.fr/es_article4375.html#) or check: [Jesus Amic](http://www.jesusamic.org/)

(*Jesus Amic* means *Jesuschrist Friend*)

> Barcelona: Common prayer every 2nd and 4th Tuesday of the month in the chapel of the Parrish of Maria Auxiliadora, Pg Sant Joan Bosco, 70, Barcelona. More info in: [prayers Taizé Sarrià](http://www.prentetemps.cat/p/pregaries-taize-sarria.html)

(Sarrià is a neighbourhood in the North part of Barcelona)

> Barcelona: Common prayer on Fridays at 21.00h in the church Josepets de Gràcia, plaça Lesseps, 25.